# is capital valued vs. property value

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can somebody explain the sentence in bold for me, please? Does it mean "the capital of The Crown Estate trust fund is $17.4 billion while the value of real estates of royal family members is $16.4 billion"?

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/capital-value
https://www.bankrate.com/glossary/p/property-value/

The wealth of Queen Elizabeth II, on the other hand, comes from different sources which is part of being a royal family member. History states that trust funds are responsible for the majority of the wealth of royal family members. **The Crown Estate trust fund, for example, is capital valued at $17.4 billion in 2019 while its property value is $16.4 billion.**

Source: https://www.ibtimes.com/queen-elizabeth-vs-trump-net-worth-who-richer-world-leader-2907867

Comment: Trust funds exist only on paper, such as bonds, certificates, shares, or in computer records, and the money in a bank does not actually exist in a box with the owner's name on it. But property forms tangible assets: "real" estate as in US parlance. So the sentence is talking about two distinct sources of wealth.

Comment: Oh! You are asking about "value" and "valued". Those phrases are constructed slightly differently with the verb "is" in a different place. So "value" has a different part of speech. "The capital is valued at..." and "the value of the property is..."